# How hide scroll fancyBox, but scroll outside?

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I hid the scrollBar at window fancyBox. 
But I do not need scrolling content inside FancyBox with a scrollBar - I need only hidden scrolling outside window FancyBox.

It is mean, that scroll must be, but invisible, and when I scroll down windows Fancy, I must scroll down all block fancyBox.

I tried to add helper:

```
helpers: {
     overlay: {
     locked: false
    }
}
```

Also I added a option `scrolling : 'no'` it hide scroll, but window Fancy is not scrolling.
It must be float block...

Comment: Mmmmmm Again what's your code, situation and try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to set `autoCenter` to `false` like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        autoCenter: false,
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                locked: false
            }
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eyd1nu3n/)**

Comment: Thank you, also how I can set fix height to iframe youtube inside?

Comment: @Fuad you also need to set `fitToView` to `false` and `height` with the integer value of your preferred height (no need to set `px`)

Comment: I ask about height iframe, because after iframe there is a HTML block, so I want that will be visible at top part window iframe(video) and after HTML. The option `height` sets height of all window, I need only Iframe video.

Comment: @Fuad : then what I would do is to set the html block as `inside` title so you don;t have to do any further calculations, check http://jsfiddle.net/7o3Lug8p/

Comment: Now I add HTML after Iframe like as: `afterLoad:function(){
                $('.fancybox-inner').append(template);}` But this solution does not show all data in block, only Iframe. For this height tells option: `fancybox-inner`